# asynchronous flask api response

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

i am returning the result from flask api. i am getting the data from the elasticsearc. the data is too large. it is taking 21 sec to get the 200 000 data. as the data increases the response become slower

is there a way to get the response faster or asynchronously?

```
class job_results(Resource):
  def get(self):
        id = request.args.get('id')       
   res = job_results_query( id)
   return (res)

def job_results_query(id):
     response = {"result":{}}
     response_query = '{\
                       "size":1000,\
                       "sort":[{"timestamp":{"order":"asc"}}],\
                       "query": {\
                         "query_string": {\
                           "query": "identifier:' + id + ' AND type:response"\
                         }\
                       }\
                     }'
    query_result = es.search(index="ab", scroll="1m", body=response_query)
    scrollID = query_result['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = query_result['hits']['total']

     while scroll_size > 0:
          response_query_time = time.time()
          for line in query_result['hits']['hits']:
                    source = line['_source']
                    a = source['a']
                    metrics_data = source['metrics_data']
                    response['result'].setdefault('a', {})
                    response['result']['a'].setdefault("data",[])
                    response['result']['a']['data'].append(metrics_data)
           query_result = es.scroll(scroll_id=scrollID, scroll="1m")
           scrollID = query_result['_scroll_id']
           scroll_size = len(query_result['hits']['hits'])

     return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask is going to block until it gets a result.  So your options are to either answer the question a different way (say, by returning an ID of a pending operation) or use a framework that supports asynchronous operation.  [Sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is designed support async with a Flask-like API.